# chain of responsibility internal field member

Tags: c#

Hi I have a quick question about how the internal field member is abe to record the different types of members that need to be approved.

```
public abstract class Approver
    {
        //internal field member that stores this
        protected Approver NextApprover;

        public void SetNextApprover(Approver nextApprover)
        {
            this.NextApprover = nextApprover;
        }

        public abstract bool ApproveMaterial(Material material, ref string reason);
    }
}
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: its not at all clear what you are asking

Comment: Are you asking why a specific kind of approver can be assigned to a parameter or field of the abstract type `Approver`?

Comment: need more info Man! its not exactly clear what you are asking about! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask